# Does every occurring type have at least one token?

Tags: identity

Do all types which occur have tokens?

> It is that between a thing, or type of thing, and (what is best called) an [occurrence](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/types-tokens/#Occ) of it—where an occurrence is not necessarily a token.

Comment: We have already discussed it at lenght in the post [types with only one token](http://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/24032/types-with-only-one-token).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA different question just same tags, i think ?

Comment: A token is the thing referenced by an occurrence.  So, of necessity, to occur requires a token.  If you have a list with seven entries for the same Mr. Jones, then there is a Mr. Jones in your list.